# How to pull in Magento 2 dev change into standard release

Tags: magento2, composer

I'm using Magento CE 2.1

There's a fix in the 2.2.x develop branch that looks likely not to be released until 2.2, so how do I pull it into my 2.1 installation?

**What I have tried**

As Magento 2 is split into modules pulled in by composer I would hope that I could just pull in an updated version of a module like module-deploy by using a version like 100.2.0-dev. I replaced using the monolithic magento/product-community-edition with the individual module requirements and changed the requested version of module-deploy. Sadly, the magento composer repo only has formal releases.

So the next thing would be to fork the module and pull in my own version for that module. However, Magento 2  seems to be a single repo, so what should I fork to just adjust a single module? Does this approach even make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I don't see this as a being a good idea and would advise against it in any environment especially if this is a production website**. The latest modules will have dependencies on other dev modules including the framework itself and depending on the amount of changed code probably would just not work.

That being said, my first thought would be to clone the Github repo, copy the existing module from the repo `app/code/Magento/<module_name>`, and replace the module in the vendor directory at `<magento_root>/vendor/magento/<module_name>` on your Magento server.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314381/how-to-correctly-require-a-specific-commit-in-composer-so-that-it-would-be-avail/) about using Github with composer.

Comment: I agree about the risks, but I take it you see the need to be able to update a single module? Sounds like you also think that there is no single repo per module, so there's no way to fork an existing repo as you essentially have to copy and paste the data from a single directory. That's what I feared.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

There is a way!!

There are two parts to this:

1. Download a copy of the module at the version you want it directly into your code base. If it's a magento module you can just add it directly into `app/code/Magento/`...
2. Add an entry into the `replace` section of `composer.json` which will tell composer "don't bother pulling in the needed dependency - I've got it locally". e.g. to replace `magento/module-braintree`, the composer.json section might look like this:

   `"replace": {
       "magento/module-braintree": "*"
   }`

This isn't perfect - it's a little hacky. But it's a way to make replacements when really needed. For example, Magento made a mistake with 2.1.8 which meant that credis needed to be at a higher version than specified in their meta-package. Using this approach I could force the correct version.

**Original answer:**
I've reverted to making my own fixes in a Magetno2fix module locally with reference to the relevant tickets so that these can be removed on upgrade. Seems a shame that we can't more easily use the fine-grained modularisation for this.